# How to use Distributed cache in partitioner hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, partitioner

I am new in hadoop and mapreduce partitioner.I want to write my own partitioner and i need to read a file in partitioner. i have searched many times and i get that i should use distributed cache. this is my question that how can i use distributed cache in my hadoop partitioner? what should i write in my partitioner?

```
public static class CaderPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, IntWritable value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to work this out is to look at the example Partitioners included with hadoop. In this case the one to look at is the `TotalOrderPartitioner` which reads in a pre-generated file to help direct keys.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/TotalOrderPartitioner.java), and here's [gist](https://gist.github.com/asimjalis/e5627dc2ff2b23dac70b) showing how to use it.

Firstly you need to tell the partitioner where the file can be found in your mapreduce jobs driver (on HDFS):

```
// Define partition file path.
Path partitionPath = new Path(outputDir + "-part.lst");
// Use Total Order Partitioner.
job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);
// Generate partition file from map-only job's output.
TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(job.getConfiguration(), partitionPath);
```

In the `TotalOrderPartitioner` you'll see that it `implements Configurable` which gives it access to the configuration so it can get the path to the file on HDFS.

The file is read in the `public void setConf(Configuration conf)` method, which will be called when the Partitioner object is created. At this point you can read the file and do whatever set-up you want.

I would think you can re-use a lot of the code from this partitioner.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i am sorry but i am really new in this area and i don't understand how this partitioner read file. is it possible for you to give me a simpler example? Thanks

Comment: I didi it. Thanks ! Thanks :))